# Pausing and Playing SpriteKit Game in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I pause and resume a game in SpriteKit in a single Scene Game (gameScene)?

```
addChild(pauseText)
self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))
```

Answer (score 2):

To pause a game from the view controller, you should call `gameView.paused = true` (where `gameView` is an SKView).

To pause a game from the scene itself, you should call `physicsWorld.speed = 0`. To un-pause the game, call `physicsWorld.speed = 1`.