# create pause function for game using spritkit

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sprite

i create a race game using spritkit

well i create button if the user click on it then it will pause the game , well my problem is that the Scene stop from moving but the car will stop slowly like the real car , i want to make stop without gravity

this is my code

```
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0,0.3);
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

this is player code

```
        playerNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "car")
        playerNode!.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: 120.0)
        playerNode!.physicsBody =
            SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playerNode!.size.width / 2)
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 1.0
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask =
        CollisionCategoryPowerUpOrbs
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
        foregroundNode!.addChild(playerNode!)
```

and finally this is the pause function

```
 if (pasueornot){ // true or false
                physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0,gravitySpeed)
            }
            else{
                physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0,0.0) // the Scene stop from moving but the car will stop slowly like the real car pasueornot
            }
```

Comment: What about using SKView's [paused](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/paused) property: like this `scene?.view?.paused = true`. Regarding to that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29662663/5327882) use `physicWorld.speed = 0` to pause the scene itself

Comment: woooow good job ,, thanks :$